# MongoDB : How to get all items where its array elements are found in another array of elements

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, product

I am using MongoClient with **JavaScript** and I have two collections , `products` and `categories`.

I'm trying to get all the categories related to the products I retrieve.

Categories has a relation field named "products" where it holds all of its product ids.

The products on the other hand , don't have a relation field.

What I need to do is get all the ids of the product query , and then somehow tell mongodb to find all the categories, **which relation products array contains a value from the main products array**.

Example:

```
categories :[ 
{
  name: "sweets",
  products:[
   "33hdhsksk243wjsjsksksjsj",
   "E383iwnsnsbdbdhnsm282",
   "Jj4i3jwnwnskdje9w9w9wjj"
  ]
},
{
name:"fruits",
products:[
 "42221+343211111sj",
 "43939€jsjakaljwiwjn3",
 "Jj4i3jwnwnskdje9w9w9wjj"
 ]
},

]


products:["42221+343211111sj", "43939€jsjakaljwiwjn3"]
```

Result of query search:

The fruits category, because some of its products are in this array (but if there was another category whose products match the same search , we should return it aswell)

Comment: Share sample source data and expected output. Also, mention the MongoDB version which you are using

Comment: I've updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is using the $in filter.

For example

```
db.collection("categories").find({products:{$in:productIds}}).toArray();
```